# Summing between two different categories within the same variable

Tags: sql, aggregate, aggregate-functions, window-functions

| Metric | Score Range | Date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 DPD | 530-579 | Apr-17 | 42.5 |
| 60 DPD | 580-619 | Oct-18 | 60.5 |

My table is above. I'd like to write a query that can create a new column that is the summation of all 30 DPD Balance values with 60 DPD Balance values for Score Range = '530-579' grouped by date. I tried using different window functions and case when statements, but I can't seem to find a good solution. Would appreciate any and all help. Here's the code I have:

```
select distinct PRODUCT,
        METRIC,
        SCORE,
        PRD_END_DATE,
        sum(value) 
        from INDUSTRY
        WHERE Metric in ('30 DPD Balance', '60 DPD Balance') and Score = '530-579'
        group by PRD_END_DATE;
```

Thanks.

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself and run into difficulties. When that happens, you can explain the problem you're having, include the relevant portion of your SQL along with the sample data you've provided, and ask a specific question about that SQL, and we'll try to help. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: What does "can't seem to find a good solution" mean? What's wrong with what you tried - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? I bet you get an error for not including PRODUCT, METRIC, SCORE in the GROUP BY clause. If you only want to group by date, remove those 3 fields from the SELECT. PRODUCT isn't even in the sample data. Why doesn't table have same field names used in query? Edit question to show desired output table. Not much of a raw sample provided.